# Transition Between Mapbox Basemap Layers

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Currently building a web application with Mapbox. I'd like to replicate the transition between basemaps, as you might see while using Google Maps:

[image]

The Mapbox API only seems to offer a [`setStyle`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/setstyle/) method for map objects, but that leads to the tiles re-rendering (Not nearly as aesthetically pleasing). My current implementation is to render two mapbox canvases, sync them and use a css-transition to fade between them. Essentially:

```
function changeStyle(input) {
    var id = input.target.id;
    var map = document.getElementById('map');
    var map2 = document.getElementById('map2');

    if(id == 'dark'){
        map.style.opacity = 1;
        map2.style.opacity = 0;
    }
    else if(id == 'satellite'){
        map.style.opacity = 0;
        map2.style.opacity = 1;
    }

}
```

See [CodePen](https://codepen.io/bransonf/pen/pojLYLM) for full implementation.

This has the obvious limitation of rendering two maps (performance cost, and twice the expense on map renders) and adds the complexity of re-rendering additional layers. Either I manipulate the maps in sync, or I re-render additional layers on transition. Regardless, this method is not sustainable.

Mapbox does have features to [load third-party vector tiles](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/third-party/) and [add a transition property to layers](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/transition/). Is it possible to load Mapbox tiles as independent layers, and use a transition property between them? Alternatively, is there a callback for loading Mapbox layers that I could use to render layers invisibly and fade in when loading is complete?

Or is it possible to implement this in a far more efficient manner than I have done so far.

Advice and discussion greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer, but the most styles don't smoothly change using setStyle because the spritesheet is different which causes a full reload. My favourite approach is to create a single style in Mapbox Studio and put each style into a folder, or name each layer with a prefix. Then go through each layer and toggle visibility. This then allows for a smooth transition, and it's exactly what setStyle would do if you had a common sprite.